# ValidationMessageFor no error message inside span

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I've looked to many other questions none of them gave me a clue. 
Here is my view :

```
<form onsubmit="return CreateNews()">
    <label>Titre : </label>
    <input id="title" type="text" name="Title" /> <div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)</div>
    <br /><label>Article : </label>
    <input id="txtEditor"></input> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Block)
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

My problem is for this line `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)` I don't get any error message inside the html generated.

The html generated :

```
class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Title" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></div>
```

Here my model:

```
public class News
{
    public int NewsID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Nom Requis")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MinLength(0,ErrorMessage="Trop Petit")]
    public string Block { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    //public Person Creator { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Not getting only this one or all other as well ?

Comment: does ur view have  `@Html.ValidationSummary(false, .....)`

Comment: @HarveySpecteur:all of them have the error message missing.

Comment: in View specify Validation Summary like :``@Html.ValidationSummary(true)``

Comment: Double check on the unobtrusive validation. Please include its scripts if not included yet.

Answer (score 1):

Check your web.config contain following appSettings

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```

I have create sample at .net fidder take a look here.

[sampe page](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MvcPage/5a9cd623d6a64bfda220cdc9a5c62591)

Code : [Code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UUJE1R)

Comment: I use this part of your code and it worked properly : @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
     <div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title)
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title, new {@class="form-control"}) 
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
     </div>
    
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success submit">Ask</button>
    }

Comment: Is it because i don't use Html.BeginForm() ? In my own code ?

Comment: I used @using (Html.BeginForm()) and now i get the error message inside my span node : <div><span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="Title" data-valmsg-replace="true">Nom Requis</span></div>
Thanks for your help.